# FileUpload doesn't work in IE8

Tags: c#, asp.net, internet-explorer, file-upload, internet-explorer-8

I'm using following buttons and label to send pdf file on the server:

```
FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" accept="application/pdf" style="display:none;"
Button ID="SelectFileButton1" OnClick="FileUpload_Click" runat="server" Text="Choose File"
Label ID="FileNameLabel1" runat="server" Width="400px"
```

and in .cs file:

```
SelectFileButton1.Attributes.Add("onclick", "document.getElementById('" + FileUpload1.ClientID + "').click();");
```

I press SelectFileButton1 choose some pdf file and `FileNameLabel1` shows the name of file.

it works fine in IE11.0 but doesn't work in IE8.0

Comment: Take a moment to read through the [editing help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) in the help center. Formatting on Stack Overflow is different than other sites. The better your post looks, the easier it will be for users to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IE 8 does not support XHR 2 API and makes asycronous uploads very hard without using an IFrame